# How do I use Autoscout24 API (Car search portal) in php?

Tags: php, api

How do I use Autoscout24 API (Car search portal) in php? I read documentation in that website. I actually configured the config file and connected to API server.

But am not able to get and display filter criteria like model, make etc with html template. Any one have good example to use this API in php?

Answer (score 0):

A PHP SDK is available from this site: http://www.developergarden.com/en/apis/docu-support/

Don't know how well it works though, I only just came across it.